# How do I verify an asset that I've created on the Stellar Transaction builder?

Tags: assets, federation

Ok so,

1. I've created my token.
2. I've attached my website's URL to the issuing address.

Now the logo next to the token is a question mark and next to Symbol/Tag it says unknown.

What is the next step here? I understand so far that it is a stellar.toml file that you need to upload to IPFS, I've tried that.

Questions:

1. How do I make a stellar.toml file? With notepad++ then save it as .toml?
2. Are there different programs or Apps to use?
3. Do I upload it to IPFS?
4. Do i have to sign it with keybase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make a stellar.toml file? With notepad++ then save it as .toml?

Any text editor will do. Just create a regular text file in UTF-8 encoding and save it as `stellar.toml`. Extension should be `.toml`, not the `.toml.txt` or anything similar.

> Are there different programs or Apps to use?
>
> Do I upload it to IPFS?
>
> Do i have to sign it with keybase?

No, no, and no.

You need to put it into the `/.well-known` sub-directory of the root website under your home domain. For example, if your home domain is `best.asset.ever.com`, then `stellar.toml` should be available at  `https://best.asset.ever.com/.well-known/stellar.toml`.

A few tips.

- Note that `stellar.toml` has to be available over `https` protocol. Setup an SSL certificate if you do not have one yet ([Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) issue SSL certificates free of charge).
- You must enable CORS on the `stellar.toml` so people can access this file from other sites. Check details [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html#enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors).

Comment: Can I do this with a website created by Wix.com? Thanks for your answer so quickly, this is what community is all about.

Comment: I'm afraid no. Wix is a high-level website builder and it doesn't allow creating sub-directories with custom content and CORS headers. You can host your main website on Wix and create a subdomain (say, `meta.yoursite.com`) specifically for `stellar.toml` and other metadata hosting.

Comment: Hmm. What website host should I use for this to be done?

Comment: Can I use GoDaddy?

Comment: Well, you definitely can use any VPS/cloud server for that purpose. Take a look at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/), they offer VPS starting from 5$/month. With [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) you can have a basic cloud server for free during the first year. GoDaddy also offer [VPS hosting](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/vps-hosting), but their plans are much more expensive alongside with a questionable performance.

Comment: Can I add the stellar.toml file to my go daddy web hosting service as shown in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_h_kGnvmR1Q thank you so much for your help thus far.